# CSS positioning issues - floating

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-float

I don't know enough about positioning yet to understand why I can't get some text to float up next to a thumbnail. I'm using a wordpress plugin to create a thumbnail of an embedded youtube video, and then I want to have the text sit inline with the thumbnail, to the right. 
I have created some divs and used CSS to try and position the elements how I'd like them, but no luck. I think some CSS from the plugin elements is preventing it from working perhaps? Just don't know how to find the offending property to override it.

You can see a test page [here](http://dev.thecyclery.net.au/home-test/video-lightbox-test/).

Thanks for taking a look!
Jon

Comment: Your link requires a login..

Comment: I'm so sorry Aytan! I think I've adjusted the privacy of this page, and perhaps try this non-shortened URL to make sure: http://dev.thecyclery.net.au/home-test/video-lightbox-test/

Comment: you want the text to sit inside the youtube icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css

```
code {
   float: left;
   margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, that did it - Thanks Eranda! I think I was trying to float the divs a bit further in, I missed the code element. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried floating your thumbnail to left:

```
thumbnail{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px; // to make things look better
}
```